# Sending and receiving signals in django models

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am using django 2.0.8 and Python 3.5. I want to be able to send and receive custom signals when an object is saved to the database.

I have followed the Django documentation on [listening to signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals) and also the [core signals bundled with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/) - however, I am unable to get my example to work.

This is what I have so far:

### myapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models
import django.dispatch

my_signal = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["name"])

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # Call the "real" save() method.
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  

        # Fire off signal         
        my_signal.send(sender=self.__class__, name=self.name)

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Exception:', e)
        #pass
```

### myapp/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Foo


@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def foo_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print('Foo Signal Recieved!')
    print(kwargs)
```

### myapp/app.py

```
class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    label = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
```

### Sample usage

```
from myapp.models import Foo

foo = Foo(name='Homer Simpson')
foo.save() # Object is saved, but event is not fired!
```

Can anyone explain why the signal is not being fired?

Comment: You could get create,update and delete informations accurately (I persume).

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried a `print('signal received')` in your code to check that it's called?

Comment: To see the format of the fixture, I would create some bogus data in code, then use `manage.py dumpdata` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) to get a dump that you can then modify.

Comment: what happens in `fooch_save` when you update the table `FoodooChile`? You should add logging to that function and run `FoodooChile.objects.create(name='test')` in the shell

Comment: @LaurentS thanks for that suggestion. I will remove that from my question and focus my question on solely how to send/receive signals.

Comment: You are not trying to connect to he right signal. I can only see a receiver on the **post_save** signal

Comment: @GharianiMohamed I don't understand. The code above is drawn from the Django signals documentation. What is missing? Care to clarify some more - perhaps in an answer?

Comment: An important Note, how did you run the code in Sample usage?? If you run this in `python manage.py shell`, you need import the signal.py first .otherwise, signal won't work.

Comment: Can you include your **myapp.__init__.py** and your **settings.py** files?

Comment: do you set `default_app_config ` in your myapp/__init__.py file? [default_app_config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `INSTALLED_APPS` from `settings.py`, specifically the part where you include `myapp`.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you need two features supplied by Django. [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) and [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

So read the doc first

The model **Activity** is related to **contenttypes**,seems you miss object_id Field, which indicate which model instance is being crud.

For every crud action, An **Activity** instance is  being created.This part is  just the code written in **signal.py**

**signal**: signal have to connect each concrete model. Fortunately,See the source code of decorator [receiver](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py).

We have a signal list [post_save,post_delete] and a model list (FoodooChile, FooBarChile) to connect .

In post_save,argument **created** indicate the action is create or update.

At last, Usually we import the signal file in urls.py, maybe not the best practice.

---

It is also related to your `settings.py`. use `'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'` replace `myapp` in `settings.py`,**or** define `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'` in `myapp/__init__.py`. The link above in comments describe this in detail

Answer (score 1):

1. In the `myapp.signals` you have a receiver that handels the **post_save** signal (`@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)`) it doesn't connect to your signal.
2. Make sure you are using your app config in the **__init__.py** of you application `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig'`
3. To connect to the signal you created try this in your signals.py file:

   ```
   @receiver(my_signal)
       def my_handler(name, **kwargs):
           print(name)
   ```

Comment: Your suggested edits are different from what the official documentation states (especially regarding point 3). With point 2, [this is no longer recommended for Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/). I still did try the suggestions you made, however, the receiver function was not called.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel, but only putting it on one side of the cart, so to speak.

the post_save signal is always sent on save, so defining your own signal is overkill. I know you got the argument there, but the receiver has the `sender` argument already, which is the saved object, so you can just do `sender.name` and you got the value you need.

Apart from that, you have a syntax error, your custom save function for your model is not indented. I don't know if this is a formatting error in your question or if that is how it looks in your code. Either way, should work if you just drop your custom signal.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models
import django.dispatch


class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

**Signals**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Foo


@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def foo_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print(sender.name)
```

**App**

```
class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    label = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
```

**Sample**

```
from myapp.models import Foo

foo = Foo(name='Homer Simpson')
foo.save()
```

Comment: I had a feeling that writing my own save signal was overkill, but I wanted to kill two birds with the same stone - i.e. **1.** send/recieve a custom signal (so I could use the logic elsewhere (i.e. for different events) **2.** get alerted on object being saved to db. Could you post an answer with my code corrected to do that? as it stands, I still don't see how what I'm doing is different from what the Django documentation recommends.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli hope it helps!